# c# / Linq to SQL - Update statement not well formed (no field in SET, all in WHERE)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-update

I like LinqToSQL because it is waaaayyy simpler to implement in a small project (versus EF) and avoids me to write/maintain SQL.

I have a lot of working Entity/tables but I face a problem with a particular class that use inheritance.

The SQL table "ChildClass" have only 3 fields : id, MyOtherField01 and MyOtherField02.  A primary key is created on "id".

here is the class [simplified] :

```
[Table("ChildClass")] 
public class ChildClass : ParentClass {
    //constructor 
    public ChildClass(){}

    //constructor that take the parent to inject property    
    public ChildClass(ParentClass ParamInject)
    { //code removed for simplicity
    }

    [Column(IsDbGenerated = true, Name = "id", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int NoUnique { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public bool MyOtherField01 { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public DateTime? MyOtherField02 { get; set; } }
}
```

Because of many reason, here is my insert/update mecanism that is able to ignore the context :

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
try
{
    using (var MyDBConnexion = new SqlConnection(MyDBConnStr))
    {
        //ouverture du context
        using (BusinessContext MyDBContext = new BusinessContext(MyDBConnexion))
        {
            MyDBContext.Log = new System.IO.StringWriter(builder);

            //If we have an insert...
            if (param_Client.NoUnique == 0)
                MyDBContext.ListOfChildClasses.InsertOnSubmit(MyChildClassInstance);
            else //if we must update
            {
                //little funky work around that normally works well, that allow me to dont care about Context
                var Existing = MyDBContext.ListOfChildClasses.Single(x => x.NoUnique == MyChildClassInstance.NoUnique);
                //than, copy the properties into the "existing"
                param_Client.CopyProperties(Existing);
            }

            MyDBContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   string strT = builder.ToString(); //Here, I have the Update statement!
   return strErr;
}
return "";
```

But for this precise class, here is the resulting SQL :

```
UPDATE ChildClass
SET  
WHERE (id = @p1 and PrivilegeActif = @p2 and DateAdhesion = @p3)
```

No field in the set section!

any ideas?

Comment: If it can Help, for the moment, the dirty work around is to avoid inheritance and have a property named "ParentClass" inside "ChildClass".

Comment: nobody?  I did'nt find the solution, and because of this problem, i fear using LinqToSQL + inheritance